# Change JTextArea color based on selected JComboBox item

Tags: java, swing

Along with a basic main thread, this will display a window with a sentence, and change the font to bold as soon as something from a drop down menu is selected.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Gui extends JFrame {

  private JComboBox box;
  private JTextField tf;
  private static String [] filename = {"button.png", "x.png"};

  public Gui(){
    super("The title is");
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    box = new JComboBox(filename);
    tf = new JTextField("This is a sentence", 14);

    box.addItemListener( new ItemListener() {
      public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event) {
        if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
          tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));
        }
      } 
    });

    add(box);
    add(tf);
  }
}
```

Is there any way of getting it to change back, if i choose the other member from the drop down menu?

Comment: Yes, you have to read the selected value & provide logic that determines what happens based on the selected value.

Comment: The post subject title is supposed to reflect the question.  Since 1) you've added the java tag 2) it is obvious that you are a beginner & 3) SO is primarily for asking questions..  The title 'java beginner question' provides absolutely no value.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
```

In order to check with item was selected, use `box.getSelectedItem()` or `box.getSelectedIndex()`.

For example:

```
public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent event){
    if(event.getStateChange()==ItemEvent.SELECTED){
        if (box.getSelectedIndex()==0) 
            tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));  //first item selected
        else 
            tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14)); //second item selected
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using getFont to see what you have, test it, and based upon your test change what you want?

Answer (score 0):

```
box.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
     public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
         tf.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.BOLD, 14));

     }
});
```

Try this!

Comment: Since the combo. already has an ItemListener (which is all that is needed to form a solution), I fail to see what this suggestion adds toward solving the OP's stated problem.